# How do I disable opening DevTools in the browser when running expo start?

Tags: react-native, expo

When I run expo start (expo cli 2.6.14) in my react native project, it always opens a browser window with the DevTools. It's a nice feature, but sometimes I'd rather not have that happen.

It says in the console:

```
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
```

But pressing shift + d just types out capital D. So I don't get why it says that. Maybe it's because I'm on a Mac, but I've tried shift/ctrl/alt/cmd + d and none of those do anything regarding disabling opening the window.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I figured it out, once the bundler is actually up and running, then you can use shift + d as one of the commands, as well as press d to open DevTools manually.

It's odd that it tells you to use the command before you're actually able to use it.

Comment: › shift+d │ toggle auto opening developer tools on startup (disabled)
Even when it says disabled it still auto-launched for Android. Seems buggy

Answer (score 0):

Using `shift + d` (in the console) toggles the browser-debugger but for me it didn't work.

Instead to bring up the menu in the app press `m` in the console and disable remote debugging from there.